# Run out of VRAM in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

Does this mean that I need more vram i am currently training the model on a gtx 1050 2 GB model

`2021-02-12 22:51:38.033037: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:419] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 84.38MiB (rounded to 88473600).  Current allocation summary follows.`

When I run the script it fetches data makes the images and splits the training data starts and finishes training gives out a couple results around 20 then it collapses

This is the model I am using for training

```
img_width, img_height = 150, 150
# Enter the number of samples, training + validation
nb_train_samples = x1 + y2
nb_validation_samples = x2 + y2
nb_filter1 = 16
nb_filter2 = 16
nb_filter3 = 32
conv1_size = 3
conv2_size = 2
conv3_size = 5
pool_size = 2
# We have 2 classes
classes_num = 2
batch_size = 10
lr = 0.001
chanDim =3

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filter1, conv1_size, conv1_size, border_mode ='same', input_shape=(img_height, img_width , 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size)))

model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filter2, conv2_size, conv2_size, border_mode ="same"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size), dim_ordering='th'))

model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filter3, conv3_size, conv3_size, border_mode ='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size, pool_size), dim_ordering='th'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(classes_num, activation='softmax'))
```

Is there any work around this problem

```
Limit:                  1406277838
InUse:                  1388972288
MaxInUse:               1388972288
NumAllocs:                  667963
MaxAllocSize:            176941568

2021-02-12 22:51:38.055777: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:424] *******x*******xx********_**********************************************************************xxxx
2021-02-12 22:51:38.055870: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1622] OP_REQUIRES failed at cwise_ops_common.cc:82 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[21600,1024] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the model architecture and data size, there is no workaround to running out of VRAM. You can try and reduce the number of filters, particularly in the first layer. You can technically train using CPU, but it will likely be extremely slow.

Comment: I even tried to train it on a gtx 1080 8GB but i get the same error is it possible that the model keeps adding to the VRAM

Comment: Can you show more of your code? I want to reproduce it but need some more info